# How do you get a launcher for firefox?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nix

I hope that I'm tagging/asking on the correct page. I'm Using **Linux Mint 6.0**, but it could be OS independent.

So the used command for installing Firefox was

```
nix-env -iA nixpkgs.firefox-esr
```

When I type `which firefox`, I get:

```
/home/foo/.nix-profile/bin/firefox
```

So Linux Mint comes with Chrome preinstalled, which has a launcher, e.g. also in the start menu. How do I get that for firefox as well? I didn't find a tool to create such a launcher in Mint and I actually think, that `nix` should do that for me.

[image: Edit Chrome Launcher]

EDIT: I also found [this page](https://www.xmodulo.com/create-desktop-shortcut-launcher-linux.html) which seemed helpful and advertised e.g. the KDE Kickoff, but I wasn't able to get that one to run.

Comment: [Home-manager](https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager) is a good way to install user apps declaratively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speak for Ubuntu launchers, but other distros will have launcher files that will have a similar setup

**TLDR**, add `~/.nix-profile/share` to `XDG_DATA_DIRS` env variable on login. Add the following to `~/.profile` after nix loading commands

```
export XDG_DATA_DIRS=$HOME/.nix-profile/share:$XDG_DATA_DIRS
```

**Explanation**:

Installed packages via `nix` will have an immutable path in `nix/store`. `~/.nix-profile/bin/firefox` is the derivation your current nix environment is linked to (if you update the firefox package, it'll point to the new one)

This means you can create a launcher file for that executable. Lets see if the `firefox-esr` derivation comes with a desktop launcher or not:

```
$ nix-build '<nixpkgs>' -A firefox-esr
```

This will build the package and give you a derivation path. For my current channel it is `/nix/store/3iipcmiykgr4p34fg3rkicdz1bw584gm-firefox-102.2.0esr`

If I check inside it, there is a `.desktop` file which defines Ubuntu launchers:

```
$ ls /nix/store/3iipcmiykgr4p34fg3rkicdz1bw584gm-firefox-102.2.0esr/share/applications
firefox.desktop
```

These files will also be available under `~/.nix-profile/share/applications` so you can simply add that to `XDG_DATA_DIRS` env variable before boot

If an application did not have one, you can manually make one and add it under `~/.local/share/applications`, then set the executable path to the nix one

Answer (score -1):

So [SuperSandro2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4446318/supersandro2000) explained in the comments, that **firefox** from **nix** ships with a `.desktop` file already. This can be easily added to the start menu and lies in

```
/nix/store/...-firefox-XXX.X/share/applications/firefox.desktop
```

---

If there is no such file included, the most direct way could be (imho) to just create a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
./home/foo/.nix-profile/bin/firefox & #Run Firefox
echo Firefox was started with PID $!
```

In order to make it runnable, enter `chmod +x your_skript_name.sh`. Afterwards, `./firefox 2> /dev/null &` can be used instead to run it silently in the background.

You can also consider [the developer/command line options for firefox *(Archive)*](https://web.archive.org/web/20190801210829/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options) or [this blog article here](https://linuxconfig.org/firefox-and-the-linux-command-line).

---

Maybe `/usr/bin/menulibre` is also the right application, it allows you to create `.desktop` files. This app can also be found by right-clicking on the start "**menu**".